# async await usages for CPU computing vs IO operation?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

*I already know that `async-await` keeps the thread context , also handle exception forwarding etc.(which helps a lot).*

But consider the following example :

```
/*1*/   public async Task<int> ExampleMethodAsync()
/*2*/   {
/*3*/       var httpClient = new HttpClient(); 
/*4*/      
/*5*/       //start async task...
/*6*/       Task<string> contentsTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
/*7*/   
/*8*/       //wait and return...  
/*9*/       string contents = await contentsTask;
/*10*/   
/*11*/       //get the length...
/*12*/       int exampleInt = contents.Length;
/*13*/       
/*14*/       //return the length... 
/*15*/       return exampleInt;
/*16*/   }
```

If the `async` method (`httpClient.GetStringAsync`) is an IO operation ( like in my sample  above) So -  I gain these things :

- **Caller** Thread is not blocked
- <strike>**Worker** thread is released because there is an *IO* operation ( IO completion ports...)</strike> (GetStringAsync uses `TaskCompletionSource` and not open a new thread)
- Preserved thread context
- Exception is thrown back

But What if instead of `httpClient.GetStringAsync` (IO operation) , I have a **Task** of `CalcFirstMillionsDigitsOf_PI_Async` (heavy compute bound operation on a sperate thread)

It seems that the only things I gain here is :

- Preserved thread context
- Exception is thrown back
- **Caller** Thread is not blocked

But I still have another thread ( parallel thread) which executes the operation. and the cpu is switching between the main thread  and  the operation .

Does my diagnostics is correct?

Comment: Note that context handling is done by the `await` keyword, not the `async` keyword.

Comment: @downvoter comments are helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you only get the *second* set of advantages in both cases. `await` doesn't start asynchronous execution of anything, it's simply a keyword to the compiler to generate code for handling completion, context etc.

You can find a better explanation of this in '["Invoke the method with await"... ugh!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/03/13/quot-invoke-the-method-with-await-quot-ugh.aspx)' by Stephen Toub.

It's up to the asynchronous method itself to decide how it achieves the asynchronous execution:

- Some methods will use a Task to run their code on a ThreadPool thread,
- Some will use some IO-completion mechanism. There is even a special ThreadPool for that, which you can use with Tasks [with a custom TaskScheduler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx)
- Some will wrap a TaskCompletionSource over another mechanism like events or callbacks.

In every case, it is the specific implementation that releases the thread (if one is used). The TaskScheduler releases the thread automatically when a Task finishes execution, so you get this functionality for cases #1 and #2 anyway.

What happens in case #3 for callbacks, depends on how the callback is made. Most of the time the callback is made on a thread managed by some external library. In this case you have to quickly process the callback and return to allow the library to reuse the method.

**EDIT**

Using a decompiler, it's possible to see that `GetStringAsync` uses the third option: It creates a TaskCompletionSource that gets signalled when the operation finishes. Executing the operation is delegated to an HttpMessageHandler.

Comment: The first set includes the fact that the IO operation is done by the driver and no by a thread , so a thread is **not waiting there**. there is no thread working here, while in the other example ( PI) - there is a thread which is working. ....please explain why do you say : _you only get the second set of advantages in both cases_...

Comment: It's the *method* that starts and uses the IO operation and returns a `Task`. `await` doesn't start anything. Check the edit for some decompiler spelunking about GetStringAsync specifically

Comment: Yes I just saw that also. it uses TaskCompletionSource. it does not run on a worker thread.so the second item on my first set is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Your analysis is correct, though the wording on your second part makes it sound like `async` is creating a worker thread for you, which it is not.

In library code, you actually want to keep your synchronous methods synchronous. If you want to consume a synchronous method asynchronously (e.g., from a UI thread), then call it using `await Task.Run(..)`

Comment: in the second part I meant : `Task.Run(()=>CalcFirstMillionsDigitsOf_PI_Async())`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct. I cannot find any wrong statement in your question. Just the term "Preserved thread context" is unclear to me. Do you mean the "logical control flow"? In that case I'd agree.

Regarding the CPU bound example: you'd normally not do it that way because starting a CPU-based task and waiting for it increases overhead and decreases throughput. But this might be valid if you *need* the caller to be unblocked (in the case of a WinForms or WFP project for example).

Comment: So youre saying that if it's a CPU heavy calculation task- then I shouldnt await for it  - and I can use a Task in a new thread instead ?

Comment: Just call CalcFirstMillionsDigitsOf_PI directly without any asynchrony involved.

Comment: but then the UI will freeze

Comment: Yes, just like I said. If you are in a UI-context don't do this. Start a new task and await it. In, say, ASP.NET you wouldn't need that.

Comment: it sounds like in asp.net i will use it (async-await) only for `I/O` operation though....(and I do use asp.net).

Comment: That's basically right. And I recommend that you do not use async in ASP.NET until you have evidence that you need it because you'd have too many threads running. ASP.NET is a very different scenario for async than client apps are. Use async only if the extra effort is worth it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36257/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-usr)